# How to evaluate equity requirement for a stealth startup?

Tags: salary, equity, start-up

I was asked for salary expectations at a stealth startup. How to go about deciding on the amount of equity when there is no information on their numbers (sales, valuation, etc.) online?

Comment: The startup probably has a business plan, from which possible valuations in the future can be made. Ask them about it.

Comment: If you can't find any info and/or don't trust the info they provide, assume the equity is worth *nothing* and ask for a cash salary at the going rate for your field/expertise